# How to safely use a "catch all" in production mode?

Tags: playframework, security, playframework-1.x

Play Framework has the file routes. This file list all the routes needed by the application.
By default, the route file has a line:

```
# Catch all
*       /{controller}/{action}                  {controller}.{action}
```

How to safely use it in production mode? Do I need to comment this line out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, ideally you should comment it in production. In fact I would comment it in development too, that way you'll notice any missing route.

Answer (score 1):

If you still want to use it in dev (for faster development, nice error messages, ...), this is how you do it:

```
#{if play.mode.isDev()}
  *   /{controller}/{action}      {controller}.{action}
#{/if}
```

Comment: It looks cool but I think that's a bad idea. You might find errors only when switching to production..

Comment: Fair enough, but you should check your routes in your functional tests.

Comment: Your functional tests would still work! You run then in test mode after all ;)